# Why am I unable to assign a function when using a type alias?

Tags: typescript

Here's my question,

```js
type WithoutIndexSignature = { email: string; token: string; password: string; };

type WithoutRecordAlias = { [P in 'email' | 'token' | 'password']: string };

type WithRecordAlias = Record<'email' | 'token' | 'password', string>;

// This doesn't work
const func1: (arg: Record<string, string>) => void = (arg: WithoutIndexSignature) => {};
// This doesn't work
const func2: (arg: Record<string, string>) => void = (arg: WithoutRecordAlias) => {};
// This doesn't work
const func3: (arg: Record<string, string>) => void = (arg: WithRecordAlias) => {};
// But this works?
const func4: (arg: Record<string, string>) => void = (arg: Record<'email' | 'token' | 'password', string>) => {};
```

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgewK7AJIDsAmEAeAynAOZYCGwqATtALxQDeUEAtuXADYBcUAzsGpwsJANxRgyANYQsvAUJHiw5PnwDuyajnmDhYqAF9RAKBOhIsBCnQAlCAGMtOAIKc4qqA2YBtAApQwlAA5GwcnMFQAD4hkjJYkTHBKmqa2sEAurqKJEam5uDQ8Ej2TtpuHnxeUKXOADyh7FyJsdKyLcmqGs7BADT8eiIAfPkA9KNQACqIcFU4yBB8CcBQaVImTlgCUABmqFgOAIy8ABTk1CS8tdp1Cvr9d8MAlF5DUABuyHA41WcXvMUbJhcARiGRKDQIC86G9GMYTOMpjM5gslsEVmsNsgtis9gcAEync6XGqOeqPEgPQYkIbQt6fb6-YkA6xoYDXVzuVR0pjwxHTWZQeaLZarLTrTbbPEOADMRP+pLKOFu1KpOVprw+Xx+DD+JMBHIq3M1cNMiIAQugJMixdQpHwAPxYnG7fYOAAs8pJHJVOTV+g1MK1jN1zMV9Ua4Q6cXa0RCKW66X9zxNxiAA)

I've been using typescript for more than a year, but this error really is unclear to me. Is it just a bug?

This error started after I updated typescript to version `4.2.4`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`func` 1,2 and 3 doesn't work because, in the function type, the parameter is `Record<string, string>`, but in the implementation, we have a type with specific properties.

Either `Record<'email' | 'password' | 'token', string>` or `{ email: string; password: string; token: string }` require the keys `email`, `password` and `token` to be present, and `Record<string, string>` doesn't ensure that, which is why they are incompatible with each other.

Now, if you make those keys optional, for example: `{ email?: string; token?: string; password?: string; }` it works because this type is compatible with `Record<string, string>`.

Here's an example of that ([on playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAZgVzMKBLcB1VUAWAlAUwEcFUAnAgEwEEyBzCGAXhgAoAPALhgG8YwAhgFsC3aGVRg6MAL4BKZgD5eMgNwAoUJFiJkaTNhwB5AA77BAG1oNmbLr37CCAfjFQJU2QqbKea9Zrg0DAC9AgiYLAsDoIi3ADkUATQ8bIaWsEUoGSU3ITZlAA84pJ0ADQwJVLK0X4a6gD0DTAA7iBkANYQ6roo6GBYuIQk5FTWEKyhdOEEkXL1DQBUMLhkIC2MBGRrZOrWM5EwIHArAJ4mBDDx%20e1FVeWV7qWKqaiMYCCwAhAQqHSCACMLJcoCAYCZQk4kmQjicoOdLvE%20LFRI8PHRVLJ4gA6dQwGAABTWFzI8KuKNejCEb1%20nkkZwuVxuOWKTykFXuLxgAIQsAoIwolBg9PhjKRjjiaNKmJk8XUiwaPSQfQMQ2IpEF41YWVu8wCTVa7S6Sr0-UGxjM-QEVnoEymBygesazTanW6vXM5tM5mtWp1OXmQA))

```
const functionWithRequiredArgs = (x: { name: string }) => {};
const functionWithOptionalArgs = (x: { name?: string }) => {};

const argument =  { name: 'test' };
const record: Record<string, string> =  {};

// works
functionWithRequiredArgs(argument);

/* throws error
Argument of type 'Record<string, string>' is not assignable to parameter of type '{ name: string; }'.
  Property 'name' is missing in type 'Record<string, string>' but required in type '{ name: string; }'
*/
functionWithRequiredArgs(record);

// works
functionWithOptionalArgs(argument);

// works
functionWithOptionalArgs(record);
```

So, if the function type is `(arg: Record<string, string>) => void` but the implementation requires `arg` to have `email`, TS can't allow the assignment since it would be possible to call the function with `{}`, which would generate a type error.

Now, `func4` is really bugging me, because you can actually get a successful compilation and get a runtime error.

```
const func4: (arg: Record<string, string>) => void = (arg: Record<'email', string>) => arg.email.toString();
func4({});
```

Executes:

```
[ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
[ERR]: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined
```

Maybe someone else can explain this...